# Свой Middleware перед AuthenticationMiddleware для создания фиктивного User для админки Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, request, middleware

помогите разобраться.
На текущий момент схема такая, есть сервер KeyCloak - сервер аутентификации и авторизации.
Мое приложение получает request с User от KeyCloak с помощью Apache mod_auth и AuthenticationMiddleware проверяет есть ли в БД пользователь, создает его и уже использует созданного пользователя.

Так как KeyCloak, в моем случае, уже содержит всю информацию о пользователе (права и полномочия) и не хочется всю эту информацию создавать в БД через AuthenticationMiddleware, поэтому создаю фиктивного User в request и уже этим User пользуюсь в приложении. Делается это потому, что если использовать AuthenticationMiddleware или RemoteUserMiddleware, требуется авторизоваться через login и password. Это уже выполнено сторонним сервисом - KeyCloak. А полученный request от сервиса надо передавать в каждый responce.

Все бы ничего, но админка Django использует AuthenticationMiddleware, а мой Middleware возможно не учитывает всех особенностей для создания User для админки Django.

Подскажите как и куда посмотреть или примерчик - создать User в request, чтобы избавиться от создания всех пользователей в БД, кроме superuser, для админки Django.

Answer (score 1):

Создавать фиктивного `User` не очень хорошая идея, ты ведь как-то хочешь отслеживать кто именно из пользователей какие операции совершал, поэтому желательно, что бы каждый вошедший имел учетку у тебя. Насчет использования пароля и логин - это совсем не обязательно, ты можешь получить учетные данные пользователя из другого сервиса, потом найти по ним пользователя у себя в бд(если такового нет, то создать) и залогинить его с помощью `login` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: Изучаю, Спасибо за ответ